# Can't Load my Ruby File

Tags: ruby, bots, pry

OK SO I Am just picking Ruby up pretty much for the kicks and giggles... and Believe me when I say I'm stumped.

I want to create a bot for my Twitch stream and do it in Ruby because I found a fairly easy tut to follow along with, along with my reasoning skills. However I'm having a very hard time getting my command prompt or pry to load the file.

Here is my file JUST IN CASE

```
require 'socket'

TWITCH_HOST = "irc.twitch.tv"
TWITCH_PORT = 6667

class Fox

def initialize
    @nickname = "mybotsname"
    @password = "I have the proper oauth here"
    @channel = "mytwitchchannel"
    @socket = TCPSocket.open(TWITCH_HOST, TWITCH_PORT)

    write_to_system "PASS #{@password}"
    write_to_system "NICK #{@nickname}"
    write_to_system "USER #{@nickname} 0 * #{@nickname}"
    write_to_system "JOIN ##{@Channel}"
end

def write_to_system(message)
    @socket.puts message
end

def write_to_chat(message)
    write_to_system "PRIVMSG ##{@channel} :{message}"
end

end
```

Now, From what I gathered, I should beable to go into my command prompt and type pry
I get this. 
[Pry](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wAFZo.png)

Now, I want to run my program which is located in a dropbox (Private use)

I'm Still very new to the concept of Repl's as I've been working with Java mostly along with very LITTLE Experience in other languages. What am I doing wrong here? Why can I not get my file to load properly? I've also tried filepathing and got this.[FilePathing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1HrkL.png)

I'm sorry if this is a stupid question. It's just driving me absolutely bat-brain crazy. The reason this is driving me bonkers is the video I was watching, he didn't do anything different other than my guess is he was using Terminal instead of Command Prompt. I Wanted originally to do this through Cygwin but upon install of Pry I lost a bunch of Cygwin files and can no longer load Cygwin, I will re-install the over all program later and see what I can from there.

Sorry for no embedded pics.

Also, any easier way to do this I'm all ears. I've tried Komodo Edit 10 but it's not playing nice ether.

Comment: Your question is unclear. How exactly are you loading your file? What happens when you do? Do you get an error message? If yes, what is the precise error message you are getting? Does the observed behavior differ from the behavior you are expecting? If yes, what is the behavior you expect, what is the behavior you observe, and in what *precise* way do the two differ? Please, post a [mcve], and maybe take the [tour], and read [ask].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Require from LOAD_PATH

A Ruby module or class file needs to be in the LOAD_PATH to `require` it with [Kernel#require](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#method-i-require). For example, if your file is named *just_in_case.rb*, you can use:

```
$LOAD_PATH.unshift '/path/to/dropbox/directory'

# Leave off the path and .rb extension.
require 'just_in_case'
```

### Load from an absolute path

If you need to provide an absolute path, then you should use [Kernel#load](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#method-i-load) instead. For example:

```
# Use the absolute path and the .rb extension.
load '/path/to/dropbox/just_in_case.rb'
```

### Caveats

There are some other differences in behavior between `require`, `require_relative`, and `load`, but they probably don't really matter within the limited scope of the question you asked except that there have historically been issues with [Kernel#require_relative](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#method-i-require_relative) within the REPL. It may or may not work as expected now, but I would still recommend require or load for your specific use case.

Comment: Couldn't quite the the LOAD_PATH one to work, but I did get the Absolute path to work, which is sufficient for me!! I tried that before and got similar errors, maybe I had a typo in my input! Thank you for clerifying :)